# IfFileExists command run 3 command lines

Tags: nsis

How do I the result of `IfFileExists` command run three lines and not only the first.

In the code below is the result of `IfFileExists` is `TemWSConfig`, must perform the 3 lines to the `NaoTemWSConfig` command.

Presently the line 2 and 3 after `TemWSConfig`, always run

```
  IfFileExists "$INSTDIR\IntegradorWS.exe.Config" TemWSConfig NaoTemWSConfig  
  TemWSConfig:        
    File "..\IntegradorWS\bin\x86\Release\AppInstalado.config"
    Rename "$INSTDIR\IntegradorWS.exe.Config" "$INSTDIR\Antigo_IntegradorWS.exe.Config"
    Rename "$INSTDIR\AppInstalado.config" "$INSTDIR\IntegradorWS.exe.Config"  
  NaoTemWSConfig:
    File "..\IntegradorWS\bin\x86\Release\IntegradorWS.exe.Config"
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for. After continued reading it seems to be contradicting. First, you claim the only the first line after the `TemWSConfig` label is running, then two lines below you claim it's only lines 2 and 3.

Comment: Anyway, there's a couple of standard things you could check. Do you have sufficient rights to write to `$INSTDIR` (see [RequestExecutionLevel](https://github.com/NSIS-Dev/Documentation/blob/master/Reference/RequestExecutionLevel.md). Also, did you declare `SetOutPath` prior to the lines you posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSIS does not skip around like this, you can verify that by switching out the problematic instructions:

```
Section
; Fake the IntegradorWS.exe.Config file for this example:
StrCpy $INSTDIR $temp
File "/oname=$INSTDIR\IntegradorWS.exe.Config" "${__FILE__}"

IfFileExists "$INSTDIR\IntegradorWS.exe.Config" TemWSConfig NaoTemWSConfig  
  TemWSConfig:        
    DetailPrint "TemWSConfig:1"
    DetailPrint "TemWSConfig:2" 
    DetailPrint "TemWSConfig:3"   
  NaoTemWSConfig:
    DetailPrint "NaoTemWSConfig:1"   

; Clean up
Delete "$temp\IntegradorWS.exe.Config"
SectionEnd
```

This means the problem must be with the `File` instruction. Make sure you have called `SetOutPath` so it knows where to extract. File extraction can be skipped if you have changed `SetOverwrite` etc.